# Oracle group by to get a record based on the length

Tags: sql, oracle

I have this data after grouping by in table, so we can see code is repeated
twice as there are different names associated with it.

But I want whenever the max length is more then get that name, otherwise, get short name,

so for

- `cs161` I need `Craig L Smith`
- `cs226` I need `C_SCHLASINGER`

Query that I used to get the below data is

```
Select code, name, max(length(name)) 
from acct 
where code in ('CS226', 'CS161')
group by code,name
```

and result is:

```
CODE             MAX(LENGTH(T1.NAME))                      NAME
CS161                      7                               C SMITH
CS226                      13                              C SCHLASINGER
CS161                      13                              CRAIG L SMITH
```

Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The requirement is a bit unclear... you may have more than one "name" associated to a "code", and you want to select the longest one? What if there are two names tied for the same length (for the same code)? In any case, you probably meant to group by code alone (not by code AND name - that produces no grouping at all).

Here is an elementary solution, picking all the names of same (greatest) length if there are ties; otherwise it just picks the longest, if there is only one with the longest name.

```
select code, name
from   acct a
where  length(name) = (select max(length(name)) from acct where code = a.code)
;
```

Or, using GROUP BY and a join (instead of correlated subquery):

```
select a.code, a.name
from   acct a inner join 
            (select code, max(length(name)) as max_len from acct group by code) b
              on a.code = b.code and length(a.name) = b.max_len
;
```

Here is a more advanced solution; for a given code, it picks the longest name, and if two are tied for longest, it picks the first in alphabetical order. So it returns only one name per code in all situations.

```
select code, min(name) keep (dense_rank last order by length(name)) as name
from   acct
group by code
;
```

Demo (for both approaches):

```
with
     acct ( code, name ) as (
       select 'CS161', 'C SMITH'       from dual union all
       select 'CS226', 'C SCHLASINGER' from dual union all
       select 'CS161', 'CRAIG L SMITH' from dual union all
       select 'CS180', 'V HEUSE'       from dual union all
       select 'CS180', 'V HAUSE'       from dual
     )
select code, name
from   acct a
where  length(name) = (select max(length(name)) from acct where code = a.code)
;

CODE  NAME        
----- -------------
CS226 C SCHLASINGER
CS161 CRAIG L SMITH
CS180 V HEUSE      
CS180 V HAUSE
```

and

```
with
     acct ( code, name ) as (
       select 'CS161', 'C SMITH'       from dual union all
       select 'CS226', 'C SCHLASINGER' from dual union all
       select 'CS161', 'CRAIG L SMITH' from dual union all
       select 'CS180', 'V HEUSE'       from dual union all
       select 'CS180', 'V HAUSE'       from dual
     )
select code, min(name) keep (dense_rank last order by length(name)) as name
from   acct
group by code
; 

CODE  NAME        
----- -------------
CS161 CRAIG L SMITH
CS180 V HAUSE      
CS226 C SCHLASINGER
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply change your query to:

```
select code, max(name) from acct
where
code in('CS226','CS161')
group by code
```